# oidc_provider_not_configured error message on Spring Security 5 using OpenID connect

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, openid-connect

I recently get the following error message while trying to log in a user using Spring Security 5 and OpenId connect:

```
[oidc_provider_not_configured] An OpenID Connect Authentication Provider has not been configured. Check to ensure you include the dependency 'spring-security-oauth2-jose'.
```

I am using a Keycloak instance as the authorization server. The User is redirected to Keycloak and (after login) successfully redirected back to my Application with an authorization code.

This is where the problem occurs. The `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` uses the `ProviderManager` to get an access token. There are 3 providers configured:

- `AnonymousAuthenticationProvider`
- `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider`
- `OAuth2LoginConfigurer`

The first one is skipped, the second one returns null when the scope contains "openid" and the third one throws above error.

Why is the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider` not handling the "openid" scope? Should the  `OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider` be used instead? Why is this one not automatically configured?

`spring-security-oauth2-jose` is in the classpath as it comes with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`.

Here is my setup:

pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>security</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig.java:

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

application.yaml

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          demo:
            client-id: oauth-demo
            client-secret: [SECRET]
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: openid

        provider:
          demo:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost/auth/realms/csp/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            token-uri: http://localhost/auth/realms/csp/protocol/openid-connect/token
            jwk-set-uri: http://localhost/auth/realms/csp/protocol/openid-connect/certs
            user-info-uri: http://localhost/auth/realms/csp/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            userNameAttribute: preferred_username
```

Comment: When changing the scope to "profile" it works an I get back a valid JWT (access token). What is then the difference between those 2 scopes?